# Script policy in Azure API management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm migrating from APIGEE to Azure API management. I have a few JavaScript policies in APIGEE. But I do not see any kind of scripting policies in policy reference index (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies). This being the case what is the equivalent of APIGEE JavaScript policy in Azure API management? If there isn't any then how will we migrate those policies to Azure API management? I'm ok if  I can create completely new custom policies, if I can, but then I need some tutorial or documentation on the same to hand hold. I'm ok if that needs to be done only in C# also.

Regards
Venkatesh S

Answer (score 1):

You can use azure api management policy expression
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Comment: But you can use it as an alternative

Comment: So should I convert the javascript to c# code. Or is there way that I can executevthevc# in some javascript engine return results

Comment: You have to re-write your code using the policy expression which is C#

Comment: Will I be able to use microsoft JSCript engine in policy expression